# A canonical Swift answer for "My function with an asynchronous call returns empty data"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

There are already over 400 questions on StackOverflow with the Swift tag that relate to asynchronous execution. It feels like there has been a recent increase in the number of questions asked by low-rep users that all seem to misunderstand the same problem:

```
func getData() -> [String] {
    var data: [String] = []
    someAsyncFunc { 
        data = $0
        print(data)
    }
    return data
}

// Why does `getData() == []` even though it isn't empty when I print!?
```

Like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63047052/5078779)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63021949/how-to-use-values-after-retrieving-data-with-firebase-in-swift/63023670?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C0.0000#63023670)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943734/swift-upload-multiple-images-to-firestore-and-assign-urls-to-object/62969598#62969598)
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962769/i-cannot-access-my-array-objects-anywhere-how-can-i-access-them-in-swift/62962824#62962824)
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926123/how-to-stop-return-causing-unexpected-non-void-return-value-in-void-function/62959420#62959420)
[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62911519/swift-and-return-value-by-function)
[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900450/rows-are-empty-in-tableview-swift/62902080#62902080)
[8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62899010/swift-app-crashing-when-attempting-to-fetch-contacts/62899234#62899234)
[9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62819849/images-not-going-straight-into-array/62853826#62853826)
[10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62734649/swift-updating-variable-inside-of-data-task/62734775#62734775).

(If you would like to see more, just search for "[[swift] asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+asynchronous).") The point is that there are a lot of virtually identical questions: They all essentially deal with the above block of code; they all misunderstand that `someAsyncFunc` does not block the calling thread; and they all have the same answer.

There was a [similar post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115193/canonical-ajax-is-asynchronous-answer) on this site about Ajax almost 9(!) years ago, which suggested picking a very good answer and marking these new questions as duplicates. We could do the same thing for Swift. However, I can't find a great answer that is also general enough. Alternatively, we could keep doing what we're doing: leave a comment and let someone else give a slightly specialized answer. What is the best policy?

Comment: Either take one of the existing questions with a decently good answer and edit to make both the question and the answer great, thus turning it into a canonical Q&A on this subject. Or, if you truly can't find an existing Q&A that is worth it, ask a new one, perhaps a self-answered question.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function) seems to be the de facto canonical, based on the number of linked questions.